# Have multiples values from one condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have set up a Sheets file to have a list of the personnel of a company. Each line corresponds to a person and each column to a data of this same person. There is the date of entry in the company, the name of the person, his first name, his department, ...

I am trying to set up indicators and one of them is a problem. I would like to have the list of departments for people who joined the company on a given date ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pp5xmpwpMI1en2RaIZmDsPK5AM6EAvT7ssgCe2fcCZA/edit?usp=sharing)). Thanks to the formula in F2 in the previous file, I can obtain the value of line 2 but I would like to have all the values at once without having to apply my formula to each line.

Comment: could you manually enter the desired result?

Comment: i wrote that in H column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
=filter(D2:D;A2:A=today())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's work too !!!